# Intel Graphics Media Accelerator Driver for Mobile resets my dual screen settings on restart

Tags: drivers, reboot, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I work on a HP/Compaq 6910p laptop and in the office I use a docking station where I have a second monitor connected so that I can work dual screen. If my computer is in this docking station extra monitor configuration, and I am required to reboot, everything is fine until the Intel Graphics Media Accelerator Driver for Mobile starts. When it starts it changes the monitor settings so that they are returned to a single monitor and I have to manually change them back.

I have looked for information on how to configure the Intel GMAD to use my defaults but that doesn't seem to be the case, and to make things really interesting this ONLY happens when I'm connected to the docking station. If I am at home when the reboot happens, the next day at the office when I put the computer on the docking station everything works as expected.

I've asked my office IT department and they said that if I remove the driver it will be reinstalled during the next update, so I'm pretty much stuck with the driver even if I don't want it.

Does anyone know how I can make the Intel Graphics Media Driver for Mobile retain my settings after a reboot?